Android 14 Foreground Location Service Crash Despite Permission Granted
I'm encountering a crash on Android 14 devices after updating my app's targetSdk to 34. The crash occurs when trying to start a foreground service with the location type, even though the necessary permissions have been granted.
Permissions defined in AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Service definition:
<service
    android:name=".tracking.workout.service.WorkoutService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:foregroundServiceType="location" />

Code snippet causing the crash:
// Creating notification builder
mBuilder = getNotificationBuilder(service.getApplicationContext());
mBuilder.setForegroundServiceBehavior(NotificationCompat.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE);
styleNotificationBuilder();

// Getting crash at this line
service.startForeground(getNotificationId(), mBuilder.build(), ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION);

Crash log:
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException
Starting FGS with type location callerApp=ProcessRecord{48795b 8311:com.example.test/u0a257} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION] any of the permissions allOf=false [android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION] and the app must be in the eligible state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission

Observations:

The crash is recorded in Crashlytics but is not reproducible on my
test devices.
Google Analytics logs indicate that "GPS_PERMISSION -
allowed" was recorded before the crash

Additional Details:
Starting from Android 14, services need to be defined in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Previously, I used this service to track user steps using pedometer and GPS. For this, I had two workout modes: indoor and outdoor. Recently, to make the app compatible with Android 14, I extracted most of the code into a base service and inherited these two services. The IndoorService is now used as a data sync service, and WorkoutService is used as a location service.
Question:
What could be causing this crash specifically on Android 14 devices? Have there been any changes in how foreground services with location type are handled in Android 14, or are there additional requirements or states that the app must fulfill to avoid this crash? Do I need to ask both permissions (currently asking for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)?

I have been battling this same thing. I found the problem is because location services is disabled in privacy controls prior to reboot. When phone reboots this must be masking granted permissions.
Some interesting findings:

Location off. Reboot. in root adb run: adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED com.example.autostartactivity
results in the same error that is show in boot logs.

Open your app. Run the same exact broadcast. The service will start cleanly even if location is disabled in privacy.


For some reason opening the app must be loading permissions?
As a fix I check if LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER is enabled before launching my service. I probably violated several code conventions but this is for personal use anyway.
My broadcast receiver: spawns notification if gps is disabled. When notification is clicked it spawns a proxy activity which asks user to enable the gps.
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED") || intent.getAction().equals("com.example.autostartactivity.RETRY_SERVICE")){
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Boolean gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(gps_enabled) //just start service normally
        {
            Log.d("GPS BOOT","Locations services enabled. safe to start service");
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, AutoStartService.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", "Tap to see map");
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, serviceIntent);
        }
        else //show notification that gps is disabled and link up proxy activity
        {
            Log.d("GPS BOOT","User disabled location services. Starting foreground service from background will crash app");
            Intent enableLocationServices = new Intent(context,EnableLocationServices.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(enableLocationServices);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MyApp.CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("GPS Logging disabled")
                    .setContentText("Tap to enable gps")
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .build();
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
        }
    }
}

My EnableLocationServices activity: On completion it simulates the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast.
public class EnableLocationServices extends AppCompatActivity{
    Boolean settingsCompleted = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //show dialog to have user enable location
        Intent enableLocationServices = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(enableLocationServices);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        settingsCompleted = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(settingsCompleted) {
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Boolean gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (gps_enabled) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "GPS enabled logging will start!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Location services are required for this app to function!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            //broadcast shortcut to close loop with autostart receiver
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.autostartactivity.RETRY_SERVICE");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            this.finish();
        }
    }
}

